# Diminuir a altura de uma div

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, div

Pessoal quero fazer uma alteração na altura da `div` no meu site, porém não sei exatamente onde editar, sou novo com WordPress e não entendo muito de programação e estou meio perdido..

É a `div` da newsletter da página início do site, gostaria de editar a altura dela. para que pudesse acompanhar a altura das outras páginas..

Está é a [página](http://www.trilhadodinheiro.com.br) que pretendo diminuir a altura da `div`.
Para que fique da mesma altura da `div` desta [página](http://www.trilhadodinheiro.com.br/nicho-de-mercado).

Comment: Em relação a posição e tamanho vc edita no css e não no html(é possível, mas fora do padrão). Você deverá verifica as seguintes classes no css `titulo-texto`, `col-md-2` `icon-captura-topo` e `col-md-5`

Comment: Você quer deixar igual a da outra página ou diminuir o tamanho e manter o formato interno? Pelo que eu vi, o tema utiliza Bootstrap, só diminuir o tamanho da `div` não vai resolver, terás que olhar as classes de tamanho/grid na documentação do framework. Se quer deixar igual, basta substituir o HTML da página que será alterada pelo da página que você quer, o trecho é esse: [link](http://pastebin.com/i9cJDgLM).

Comment: Instale o Firebug no Chrome ou Firefox... Com o firebug você pode inspecionar os elementos; encontrar e editar facilmente o css dos elementos. Nesse caso a classe que envolve o newsletter com altura maior é a  .captura e as da páginas com newsletter com altura menor é .captura e .captura-minima , você precisa mudar o valor do height, no css, para o tamanho que deseja. Se não existir cria um atributo height com valor desejado. ex: height: 250px; Pode ir fazendo testes, excluindo e acrescentando elementos, e quando tiver pronto passe para o editor de textos html principal do site.

Answer (score -3):

Ola 
para alteramos a altura da div o jeito mais rapido seria através do CSS colocar um id nesta div e no tag ( ou estilo.css)nela   vc consegue alterar essa div, nela coloque height e altura desejada em (px) .
Espero q tenha ajudado:)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).